# Retrieving win10 serial key from Ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu

I own an XPS 9370 (the windows version). I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 and wiped out windows from my SSD(for college reasons). Since my XPS comes with a serial key for win 10 pro, which is there in the bios, how can I possibly retrieve the key?

Comment: Windows will automatically retrieve the key, if that’s what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo cat /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM
```

or

```
sudo xxd /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM
```

Basically, it should be in your MSDM table. But if you re-install windows (if you have not changed the hardware) it should automatically activate. Also Windows keys can now be tied to the Microsoft account. If you have done so, when you reinstall windows, just sign into your Microsoft account, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to ever retrieve the key.

If you reinstall Windows on that machine it will still be valid & will read it itself from the machine.
If you want to install on another machine, the license is not portable, so the key is no use to you.

Comment: What about install it in virtual machine on same physical machine?

Comment: That would require a new license.

Comment: You are assuming it was an OEM install, I think.